# Does using the UID as a key serve to prevent CSRF attacks?

Tags: security, csrf

The UID of a user logged into an application is used as a key to record in a database, as in the example below:

https://example.com/foo/uid/setitem

Even with this implementation, can a user still perform a CSRF attack on that application? How?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the uid is a hash or some string that can not be guessed or got. Your method can prevent CSRF. But this method is not a good way. because that as the uid dose not change(usually a uid never change for one user), so if the attacker get this, and he can attack. So to prevent CSRF, the best way is that generate a CSRF_token for the api that you want to protect. For these apis,  when the client requests, it must contains the CSRF_token (in the header,post form or in the url itself. Do not contain this in cookie due to cookie may be got by XSS attack).